# OpenCV C++. Returning a Mat then saving it to file

Tags: c++, opencv

I keep getting Segmentation Faults with this basic code. I'm new to C++ and could really use a hand. This is a code snippet from what is causing problems.

```
int main ()
{

cv::Mat pic1;

pic1 = takePicture();

imwrite("/home/pi/***/images/pic1.jpg", pic1);

}

cv::Mat takePicture(){
    cv::Mat pic;
    VideoCapture cam(0);
    while(!cam.isOpened()){
        std::cout << "Failed to make connection to cam" << std::endl;
        VideoCapture cam(0);
    }
    cam >> pic;
    return pic;
}
```

I checked the following link before posting this question but what was said didnt seem to help. I have tried passing by reference too.
[OpenCV changing Mat inside a function (Mat scope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235187/opencv-changing-mat-inside-a-function-mat-scope)

Comment: what if you do "return pic.clone()"?

Comment: That worked. Thanks Ivan. But why? Whats going on here :S

Comment: to explain: the capture is overwriting your picture already, while you're trying to save it. that's why you need to clone it ( save a copy )

Answer (score 1):

This is what a dry run from seeing your code tells me:-

When you say `pic1 = takePicture()` it calls the copy constructor of cv::Mat. The copy constructor of cv::Mat works by only copying the **header**, not the **entire data**. As a result when `pic` goes out of scope, it's object is destroyed and so is the data.

You could do `pic1 = takePicture().clone()`

More information about the copy constructor available here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11019585/1933672